# Web Api returning result in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

assuming we have a code like the below:

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(MyModel model){

        //.......
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("my url", stringContent, cts.Token);

        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.NotFound: return NotFound();
            case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized: return Unauthorized();
                .
                .
                .
            default:
                return new OkObjectResult(response);
        }
    }
```

How can I return the result from the first API without switch cases?

Comment: `return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode);` will return an empty response with the appropriate status code, but it's hard to tell what you really want to do in the success case (it's unlikely that `return new OkObjectResult(response);` is what you want). Also, you should dispose your response when you're done with it (ideally with a `using` statement).

Comment: you could do a `return ResponseMessage(response );', means pass the resopnse from external api as is to the callee

Answer (score 0):

you have to return content of response

```
var result=response.Content;

 return Ok(result);
```

if your content is json, it is recommened to deserialize it before return

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var result=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(response.Content);
```